# How to receive messages from IBM MQ JMS using spring boot continuously?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq

I have spring boot application which receive JSON requests and push it into IBM MQ JMS queue. There can be n number of JSON requests will be pushed to the queue. My Goal is to process each request from the queue. How can i listen to the queue and get the messages one by one to process using spring boot ?

Comment: I am facing issue with creating spring-boot application with IBM Mq. Could you please help me as I am unable to make connection to Websphere MQ.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to implement listener as:

1: Create configure following:

```
@Bean
public MQConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory(){
  MQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new MQConnectionFactory();
  connectionFactory.setHostName(); //mq host name
  connectionFactory.setPort(); // mq port
  connectionFactory.setQueueManager(); //mq queue manager
  connectionFactory.setChannel(); //mq channel name
  connectionFactory.setTransportType(1);
  connectionFactory.setSSLCipherSuite(); //tls cipher suite name
  return connectionFactory;
}


@Bean()
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer myMessageEventContainer() {
  DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
  container.setAutoStartup(true);
  container.setConnectionFactory(mqConnectionFactory);
  container.setDestinationName(//queue name//);
  container.setMessageListener(new MyEventListener());
  return container;
}
```

2: Implement message listener:

```
public class MyEventListener implements MessageListener {

  @Override
  public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
      if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
        String stringMessage = textMessage.getText();
        //do something with your message from queue
      }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
      //catch error
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Add 'mq-jms-spring-boot-starter' dependency in pom.xml as below:

Add below properties in application.yaml:

```
  mq:
    queue-manager: queueManager
    conn-name: connName(port)
    channel: channelName
    ssl-cipher-suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 or whatever ur app supports
    use-i-b-m-cipher-mappings: true (if using topic otherwise skip this property)
```

Add below annotation @JmsListener to your listener method

```
@EnableJms
Public class Consumer{
   @JmsListener(destination = "QueueNameToListenTo")
    public void listener(Object message) {
       logger.info("message received {}",message);
       //do something
    }
}
```